# what input should be given while creating hyperbox for neural network?(Fuzzy Min Max Neural Network classification))

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic

I am Currently Working on Project  "Fuzzy Min Max Neural Network Part 1: Classification"
By going through paper I understood the concept of project but not able to decide how to create Hyperbox for input pattern. And no informaton is Available on internet.
I am using Java Technology.

And I am Using PID datset.

link for the paper:
ftp://ftp.inf.ufrgs.br/pub/SIA/refer%EAncias/fuzzy%20min%20max%20classifier.pdf

I want to ask that while creating hyperbox all the parameters of input dataset should be used or work can be done with single parameter also and what should be the size of hyperbox   that we have give initally before creating hyperbox ( 0 < size of hyperbox <1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PID data set is having 9 attributes. select 2 or more than 2 attributes and than apply your algorithm to create hyperbox.